# Is there a way to get back special forms after redefining them?

Tags: scheme, racket

Scheme and Racket do not protect special forms, so it's possible to redefine them. Just purely out of curiosity, is there a way to get back special forms after they have been overwritten?

Example situation:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.11.
> (define define 1)
> (+ define define)
2
> (define x 3)  ; How to get the original 'define' back?
; x: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
>
```

If I redefine a special form, is there a way to get back the special form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically in the REPL, where definition overriding is possible, you can simply `(require (only-in racket/base define))` to get `define` back.

```
Welcome to Racket v7.3.
> (define define 1)
> (+ define define)
2
> (require (only-in racket/base define))
> (define x 3)
> x
3
```

---

For Racket files/modules, a simple answer is that once you make a top-level definition, you can't redefine it. However, you can still `(require (only-in racket/base [define racket:define]))` (rename `define` from `racket/base` as `racket:define`), and then use `racket:define` instead. Also note that while you can't redefine a top-level definition, you can shadow it, so you can use `define` in the body of `(let-syntax ([define (make-rename-transformer #'racket:define)]) ...)` for instance.

But note that in Racket, you can override [`#%module-begin`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._~23~25module-begin%29%29) which has a complete control of your file/module, so you can use this feature to create a new language that allows you to redefine top-level definitions, though at that point you are no longer using the "real" Racket.